# Create postgres table from pandas dataframe into specific schema

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two schema in PostgreSQL i.e public schema and Staging schema. Then from pandas dataframe I tried to create table in Staging schema, so I tried this method.

```
# establishing connection with database using sql alcemy
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:root@localhost:5432/TestWarehouse')
sales_df_col.to_sql("Staging.tblsalesdata",engine)
```

Then instead of creating table in Staging schema, table name 'Staging.tblsaledata' was created in public schema. How can I create table 'tblsalesdata' into Staging schema from pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation: [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), you need to pass schema as a separate parameters.

Try:

```
sales_df_col.to_sql("tblsalesdata",engine, schema='Staging')
```